# How to refer to the last cell in a row in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

Which function can I use to get the value of the last not empy cell in a row in Excel 2010?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a regular worksheet function, this might work... you do need to restrict the range, but this will provide the last number, last text string, or last anything.  This example shows a column, but works the same for a row range:

Number: **=LOOKUP(2, 1/ISNUMBER($A$1:$A$30), $A$1:$A$30)**

Text: **=LOOKUP(2, 1/ISTEXT($A$1:$A$30), $A$1:$A$30)**

Anything: **=LOOKUP(2, 1/($A$1:$A$30<>""), $A$1:$A$30)**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this for indpendance from the active sheet

```
Function LastCellInRow(rw As Range) As Variant
    LastCellInRow = rw.EntireRow.Cells(1, rw.Worksheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Value
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this VBA function:

```
Function LastInRow(intRow As Integer) As Variant
    LastInRow = Cells(intRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Value
End Function
```

Likewise, this function will return the value of the last non-empty cell in a column:

```
Function LastInColumn(strColumn As String) As Variant
    LastInColumn = Cells(Rows.Count, strColumn).End(xlUp).Value
End Function
```

Comment: These will return the last value on the `active` sheet only.